# Building software collections metapackage fails under Fedora 20/21

Tags: redhat, fedora

I am having some problems in building a software collections metapackage under fedora 20 or 21.  It works ok under RHEL7/RHEL6/Fedora19.  I get the same error if I just copy the example on the software collections website (https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/docs/guide/#sect-Creating_a_Meta_Package)

The error I get is (assuming my scl is named 'myscl')

```
error: File not found: /home/user/rpmbuild/BUILDROOT/myscl-1-1.fc21.x86_64/opt/rh/myscl/myscl
```

It looks like the software collection name is getting repeated for some reason.

As I say this works fine on RHEL7, where the scl-utils* packages are older.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with scl-utils-2.0 is it possible only to build new type of collections.

Instead of using following structure in your metapackage specfile

```
cat >> %{buildroot}%{_scl_scripts}/enable << EOF
export PATH=%{_bindir}\${PATH:+:\${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=%{_libdir}\${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:\${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
export MANPATH=%{_mandir}:\$MANPATH
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=%{_libdir}/pkgconfig\${PKG_CONFIG_PATH:+:\${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}}
EOF
```

you should use

```
cat >> %{buildroot}%{_scl_scripts}/%{scl} << EOF
#Module1.0
prepend-path    X_SCLS              %{scl}
prepend-path    PATH                %{_bindir}
prepend-path    LD_LIBRARY_PATH     %{_libdir}
prepend-path    MANPATH             %{_mandir}
prepend-path    PKG_CONFIG_PATH     %{_libdir}/pkgconfig
EOF
#automaticaly create enable script for compatibility
%scl_enable_script
```

See
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1188862
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1180638